# Openshift: Unable to access service by cluster hostname

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I setup an OpenShift environment on my Mac with following versions:

```
Mac OS Sierra, Version:10.12.2 (16C67)
oc v1.5.0-alpha.2+e4b43ee
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth
```

I was able to get the developer version running by doing a `oc cluster up` and gave the `developer` user administrative rights. Next, I added `postgres` container by issuing the following command:

```
oc new-app https://github.com/MojoJojo/authenticated-payments.git --name="postgres-keycloak" -l name="postgres-keycloak" --context-dir=postgres-keycloak
```

The command worked as expected and created a service with a `Cluster Hostname` and a `Cluster IP` address. The 'Cluster Hostname` in the admin console is reflecting as:

```
~ ❯❯❯ oc describe service/postgres-keycloak
Name:           postgres-keycloak
Namespace:      authenticated-collections
Labels:         app=postgres-keycloak
                name=postgres-keycloak
Selector:       app=postgres-keycloak,deploymentconfig=postgres-keycloak,name=postgres-keycloak
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:             172.30.123.160
Port:           5432-tcp    5432/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:   None
No events.


~ ❯❯❯ oc describe pods/postgres-keycloak-2-8r9n5                                                                                                                                                                       ⏎
Name:           postgres-keycloak-2-8r9n5
Namespace:      authenticated-collections
Security Policy:    restricted
Node:           192.168.65.2/192.168.65.2
Start Time:     Mon, 23 Jan 2017 03:24:41 +0200
Labels:         app=postgres-keycloak
                deployment=postgres-keycloak-2
                deploymentconfig=postgres-keycloak
                name=postgres-keycloak
Status:         Running
```

Next, I created another container as below:

```
oc new-app https://github.com/MojoJojo/authenticated-payments.git --name="jboss-keycloak" -l name="jboss-keycloak" --context-dir=jboss-keycloak
```

The above Git repository has a `Dockerfile` that declares the following environment variables:

```
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=postgres-keycloak.authenticatedcollections.svc.cluster.local 

POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
```

I verified and the above environment variables are being set properly in the second container. 
The problem is that the second service is not able to connect to the 'postgres-keycloak' database in the first container.

Upon further investigation, I found that while I can ping POD, Cluster IP and Cluster hostnames, the `psql` client is only able to connect if I use the pod's IP address directly. My conclusion so far is that the DNS resolution is working fine - it is just the service configuration that seems a little messed up. It seems that the service proxy is not forwarding the request to the containers.
Also, I'm not sure if the `Endpoint` count (Zero) in the above extract is the cause of the problem? My understand is that `Endpoints` are only used when services are accessed from outside the cluster.

I've tried installing other services like a web server for testing but it seems like none of the `Cluster Hostnames` or IP addresses work.

I would really appreciate any tips, hints and pointers to help troubleshoot and fix this issue.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I see that the namespace is `authenticated-collections`, but in the env variable you used `authenticatedcollections`.

I think it should be something like this:

```
POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=postgres-keycloak.authenticated-collections.svc.cluster.local
```

Is it just a typo in question or misconfiguration?
Also, I assume that both pods run in the same project.